# in Blazor, how to configure some visual properties of the pages using variables assigned with data from a text file?

Tags: blazor-server-side

In wwwroot/Info I've got a file named config.txt with this content:

ColorFondo: <chosen background color, for instance: azure>

FontSize: <chosen font size, for instance: 20px>

MainLayout.razor

---

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase


@{
    Config.Iniciar();
}

<div class="page">
    
        <div class="sidebar">
            <NavMenu />
        </div>

        <main>

            <article class="content px-4">
                <style>
                    body {
                        background-color: @Config.ColorFondo;
                    }

                    p {
                        font-size: @Config.FontSize;
                    }
                </style>

                @Config.ColorFondo;
                @Body

            </article>
        </main>

</div>
```

---

Config is an abstract class, for global variables

In Config.Iniciar()  the config.txt file is read and the related global variables are loaded with the corresponding values

**All this works out**: when I change the values in config.txt, the background (ColorFondo) and fontsize change accordingly.

**PROBLEM!!**: changes are not reflected (probably not re-read) until web server (IIS) is re-initialized. Any kind of file cache ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem:

To avoid re-reading Config.txt continously I had the following code at the begining of Config.Iniciar():

```
private static bool iniciado;

if (iniciado) return;
iniciado= true;
```

What happens:

Blazor treats an abstract class as Global for the application session, sharing it between clients sessions. So, once I set iniciado=true, it is true for any client session.

I guessed this substituting the previous code for:

```
public static int Contador = 0;

if (Contador >0) then return;
Contador++;
```

and writting @Config.Contador before @Body in MainLayout

the contador increases as the user initiates a new session even in a diferent machine or navigates the application pages

the contador never gets back to 0 until you re-initiate the application (i.e. re-initiating IIS)